# SQL Error:- The statement has been terminated

Tags: php, sql-server, xslt

My code suppose to insert data into sql server but instead I got that error after I submit the data. 
I've googled the error message but since it didn't describe my error much so I couldn't find suitable solutions. Thanks fo helping!

```
   /* -------------  PHP functions ------------- */
   function isDuplicateName( $paramId, $paramName ) {
        $conn = new DBMsSQL(); 
        $query = "select 1 from vacancy_master ".
                    "where status in (1,2) and jobtitle = ".Common::QuoteString($paramName);                        
    if ($paramId != '0') 
        $query = $query." and jobrequestid != $paramId"; 

    $conn->Query($query);                                                                   

        return ($conn->GetRows() > 0);
    }  //end of function

    function isDepartmentExists( $paramId ) {
        $conn = new DBMsSQL(); 
    $query = "select 1 from vacancy_master where jobrequestid = $paramId"; 

    $conn->Query($query);

        return ($conn->GetRows() > 0);    
   } //end isExistanceDepartment


   /* -------------  form variables  ------------- */
   $gotonewpage = $_REQUEST["gotonew"];
   $dowhat = $_REQUEST["dowhat"];
   $param = "";

   $jobrequestid = $_REQUEST["jobrequestid"];
   $department = $_REQUEST["department"];
   $deptid = $_REQUEST["deptid"];
   $requestby = $_REQUEST["requestby"];
   $deptname = $_REQUEST["deptname"];
   $budget = $_REQUEST["budget"];
   $jobtitle = $_REQUEST["jobtitle"];    

   $conn = new DBMsSQL();
   /* -------------  actions  ------------- */         
    switch ($dowhat) {          
        case "add": //insert into vacancy master table.                                                     
            $pageid = PG_DEPT_MNT_NEW_MGMT;           //constant from moduleconstant.php

            //duplicate job name checking                               
        if(isDuplicateName("0", $jobtitle)){                                 
                $ok = "/humanresources/vacancynew.php";
            MessageBox::Info(21592,$param,"",$ok);
            //****************Audit Log**********************************
            $action = MessageBox::LogInfo(21592,'');
            Common::AuditLog($modifyid, $moduleid, $pageid,$action,CT_ERROR);

            exit(1);
            } //end if
```

sequence number (jobrequestid) accumulates every time I submit a new record

```
            $jobrequestid = Common::getSeqNum("jobrequestid");                  

            $insert = "insert into vacancy_master (jobrequestid, requestby, department, budget, jobtitle) ".
                            "values ( $jobrequestid, ".Common::QuoteString($requestby).","." $department, $budget, ".Common::QuoteString($jobtitle)."); ";

            Common::AuditLog($modifyid, $moduleid, $pageid, $insert, CT_DB);        
            $conn->Query($insert);
            $msgid = 21531; $param = $jobtitle;
            break;
```

Comment: I highly recommend you learn about parametrised/prepared statements and start using them first. What you have appears to be very open to injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for my dumbness, there are columns weren't marked as "allowed null" are in my table but not used in my code. 
After I removed those columns my codes work successfully.